# Mixed Content strange https issue with https iframe

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure resource 'http://yyy'. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**But it is https://yyy iframe.**

I switched off JS in the browser and definitely see that iframe src = "https://yyy" , the page contains only one this iframe, after updating page everything becomes fine...

On my computer(Linux Mint) it reproduces in Firefox and Chrome , on other
computers(Windows, Centos) it reproducible only in Chrome or only in firefox.

Any ideas would be higly appreceated..

Comment: well something is loading `http://yyy` - perhaps you don't understand the html or maybe some javascript is doing it - browsers rarely lie about exceptions

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I switched off JS and searched in html sources , nothing..

Comment: Also check that when requesting `https://yyy` you're not getting redirected to `http://yyy`.

Comment: @Kieran Potts , yeah that's it , thanks a lot man!!! Transform it into the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check that when requesting `https://yyy` you're not getting redirected to the non-secure HTTP version: `http://yyy`.